# Apex trigger, Code coverage is on 32 % not sure way

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am new Apex, need some help, my code coverage is 32% on this follwing trigger, 
not sure where I am doing somthing wrong, please advise - thanks.

My Apex Trigger

```
trigger BudgetCounter1 on Tactic__c (after insert, after update, after delete) { 
 set<id> SIdSet = new set<id>();
  List<Strategy__c> lstGoalToUpdate = new List<Strategy__c>();
  Map<Id,Strategy__c> mapStrWithId = new Map<Id,Strategy__c>();

  if(trigger.isInsert){
    for(Tactic__c t : trigger.new){
      if(t.Proposed_FY_Budget__c != null){
          SIdSet.add(t.Strategy_ID__c);
      }
    }
  }
  if(trigger.isUpdate){
      for(Tactic__c t : trigger.new){
          if(t.Proposed_FY_Budget__c != trigger.OldMap.get(t.Id).Proposed_FY_Budget__c){
              SIdSet.add(t.Strategy_ID__c);  
          }
           if (t.FY_Spend_to_Date__c != trigger.OldMap.get(t.Id).FY_Spend_to_Date__c){
               SIdSet.add(t.Strategy_ID__c);  
      }
    }
  }
    if(trigger.isDelete){
    for(Tactic__c t : trigger.old){
        if(t.Proposed_FY_Budget__c != null){
          SIdSet.add(t.Strategy_ID__c);
      }
    }
  }
  if(!SIdSet.isEmpty()){
    for(Strategy__c Srec :[SELECT Id,Proposed_FY_Budget__c,FY_Spend_to_Date__c,(SELECT Id,Proposed_FY_Budget__c,FY_Spend_to_Date__c FROM Tactics__r) FROM Strategy__c WHERE Id IN :SIdSet]){  
          Decimal tot1 = 0;
          Decimal tot2 = 0;
          for(Tactic__c Trec : Srec.Tactics__r){
              if(Trec.Proposed_FY_Budget__c!=null){
                tot1 = tot1 + Trec.Proposed_FY_Budget__c;      
            }
               if(Trec.FY_Spend_to_Date__c!=null){
                tot2 = tot2 + Trec.FY_Spend_to_Date__c;      
            }
    }
         Srec.Proposed_FY_Budget__c = tot1; 
         Srec.FY_Spend_to_Date__c = tot2; 
         mapStrWithId.put(Srec.Id,Srec);
   }
 }
  if(mapStrWithId != null && mapStrWithId.values().size() > 0){
      update mapStrWithId.values();
  } 
}
```

Test Class .

```
@isTest 
public class BudgetCounter1TestClass {

    static testMethod void testMethod1() 
    {
        Tactic__c obj = new Tactic__c();
        obj.Tactic_Short_Description__c='Short Description';
        obj.Tactic_Type__c='Media';
        obj.Tactic_Status__c='In Progress';
        obj.Strategy_ID__c='a0b4B000000UnQSQA0';

        insert obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your trigger, you have `isInsert`, `isUpdate`, and `isDelete`. In your test class, you only have `insert`. 1/3 ~ 32%

Comment: @martin - sounds like the answer to me. Maybe add how to check which line are not covered if you decide to add it as an answer

Comment: @martin, you could put as an answer

Comment: sure, writing it up now.

Answer (score 3):

When writing a test class, the first thing you need to do is consider how the code should behave. In you trigger, you have:

- A new tactic is inserted with a proposed fy budget -> the parent strategy is updated to include that budget.
- A new tactic is inserted without a proposed fy budget -> the parent strategy is not updated.
- An existing tactic is updated and the proposed fy budget has been changed -> the parent strategy is updated.
- An existing tactic is updated and the fy spend to date has been changed -> the parent is updated.
- An existing tactic is updated and neither the proposed fy budget nor the fy spend to date have been changed -> the parent is not updated.
- An existing tactic with a proposed fy budget has been deleted -> the parent is updated.
- An existing tactic without a proposed fy budget has been deleted -> the parent is not updated.
- An existing tactic with a fy spend to date has been deleted -> the parent is not updated.

All of these cases should have a test method to assert that the trigger behaves the way you expect.

Taking the last case as an example:

```
@TestMethod
public static void testDeleteWithSpendToDate(){
    // create a strategy
    Strategy__c s = new Strategy();
    insert s;

    // create a few tactics
    list<Decimal> Budgets = new list<Decimal>{100,200,300,NULL};
    list<Decimal> SpendToDates = new list<Decimal>{1,2,3,NULL};
    list<Tactic__c> tlist = new list<Tactic__c>();
    for (Integer i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) tlist.add(new Tactic__c(Proposed_FY_Budget__c = Budgets[i], FY_Spend_to_Date__c = SpendToDates[i], Strategy_ID__c = s.Id));
    insert tlist;
    tlist[3].FY_Spend_to_Date__c = 4;
    update tlist[3];

    // delete one of the tactics
    delete tlist[3];

    // requery the strategy to get the values after the delete
    Strategy__c sAfter = [SELECT Id,Proposed_FY_Budget__c,FY_Spend_to_Date__c FROM Strategy__c WHERE Id = :s.Id];

    // assert the expected values
    System.assertEquals(600,sAfter.Proposed_FY_Budget__c);
    System.assertEquals(10,sAfter.FY_Spend_to_Date__c);  

    // If you are thinking that this last assert should be 6 instead of 10, 
    // you might want to take a closer look at your trigger.
    // This is why we do unit testing.
}
```